# How to disable system beep on PeppermintOS

Tags: peppermint

I've been noticing that my fresh installation of PeppermintOS has been making a loud beep anytime I enter an invalid key or open the shutdown/logout menu. I believe the beep is the motherboard's (bios) beep, which for some reason has been used to alert users in the aformentioned situations. This beep tends to startle me and the people around me, so I'm looking for a way to disable (just) it on a system-wide basis.

I've skimmed through most of the graphical setting managers provided with PeppermintOS, but I have yet to find such a setting that affects the beep system-wide. This leads me to believe I'll have to modify some system/config file, but I don't know what or where that would be. Any ideas on what to do from here is greatly appreciated.

For reference, my PeppermintOS build info is:

**Version:  *Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)***
**Kernel:   *5.10.0-21-amd64***

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works for me. Using the guide found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModuleBlacklisting) I was able to block the `pcspkr` module from loading, which disables the beep while retaining system audio. The following is a summary of what I did:

- Create conf file for `pcspkr` module, named `pcspkr.conf`, and add line for blacklisting `pcspkr`:

  ```
  touch pcspkr.conf
  echo "blacklist pcspkr" | cat > pcspkr.conf
  ```
- Then move the `pcspkr.conf` file into the `/etc/modeprobe.d` directory:

  ```
  sudo mv pcspkr.conf /etc/modeprobe.d/
  ```

Finally, the source linked above also recommends running the following two commands:

```
sudo depmod -ae
update-initramfs -u
```

but, for me `depmod` threw a warning about `-e` and the `update-initramfs` command wasn't found; so I'm not sure either lines are actually necessary.

Regardless, from here I closed everything down and restarted my system. Upon booting, anything that would have caused the beep no longer does and I'm still able to hear the audio from sites like YouTube.

**Edit:**

You can use the following command to make the blacklist take effect, rather than restarting the system:

```
sudo rmmod pcspkr
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this as **root**:

```
modprobe -r pcspkr
```

Check https://superuser.com/questions/15770/what-is-the-best-way-to-turn-off-the-ubuntu-beep-permanently

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ended up figuring it out, but if I hadn't the link you gave me would have been a great help. I'm going to edit my answer to include the restart workaround presented by your link, though, since it's more efficient.